# Splitting up Firebase Snapshots into smaller pieces?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

For testing purposes, I created a specific node on my Firebase database. I copy a user over to that node and then can futz with it without worrying about corrupting data or ruining a user's info. It works really well for my purposes.

I've run into a problem, however. If a user has an extremely large set of data, the copy function won't work. It just stalls. I don't get any errors, though. I read that Firebase has copy limits of 1MB, and I'm guessing that's the problem. I'm running up against that wall, I think.

Here is my code:

```
func copyToTestingNode() {
    
    let start = Date()

    // 1 . create copy of user and then modify the copy
    guard var copiedUser = user else { print("copied user error"); return }
    copiedUser.userID = MP.adminID
    copiedUser.householdInfo.subscriptionExpiryDate = 2500000000
    
    // 2. get a snapshot of the copied user's info
    ref.child(user.userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (userSnapshot) in
        
        print("Step 2 TRT:", Date().timeIntervalSince(start))

        // 3. remove any existing data at admin node, and then...
        self.ref.child(MP.adminID).removeValue { (error, dbRef) in
            
            print("Step 3 TRT:", Date().timeIntervalSince(start))

            // 4. ...copy the new user info to the admin node
            self.ref.child(MP.adminID).setValue(userSnapshot.value, withCompletionBlock: { (error, adminRef) in
                
                print("Step 4 TRT:", Date().timeIntervalSince(start))

                // 5. then send user alert and stop activity indicator
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.showSimpleAlert(alertTitle: "Copy Complete", alertMessage: "Your copy of \(copiedUser.householdInfo.userName) is complete and can be found under the new node:\n\n\(copiedUser.householdInfo.userName) Family")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Options:**

1. Is there a simple way to check the size of the `DataSnapshot` to alert me that the dataset is too large to copy over?
2. Is there a simple way to split up the snapshot into smaller pieces and overcome the 1MB limit that way?
3. Should I use Cloud Functions instead of trying to trigger this on a device?
4. Is there a way to somehow "compress" the snapshot to be smaller so that I can copy it easier?

I'm open to suggestions.

**UPDATE #1**

1. I read about the size limitation [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits). Judging from Frank's reaction, I'm guessing my understanding of that limitation is wrong.
2. I downloaded the node from the Firebase console and checked its size. It's 799 KB on my hard drive. It's a large JSON tree, and so I thought that its size must be the reason why it won't copy over. The smaller nodes copy over no problem. Just the large ones have trouble.

**UPDATE #2**

I'm not sure how to show the actual data, other than a screenshot, seeing how large the JSON tree is. So here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the data has multiple nodes, some of which are larger than others. I suppose I can cut down the 'Job Jar' node, but the rest really need to be that size for everything to work properly.

Granted, this is one of the largest datasets I have among all my users, but the structure doesn't change.

As for the speed of execution for each line of code, here are the simulator times for each numbered step:

Step 2 TRT: 0.5278879404067993

Step 3 TRT: 0.6249579191207886

Step 4 TRT: 1.8466829061508179

ALL DONE COPYING!!

This only works for the smaller datasets. For the larger ones, I never get to step 4. It just hangs. I let it run for several minutes, but no change.

Comment: 1) "I read that Firebase has copy limits of 1MB" Where did you read this? 2) Instead of assuming that the size of the node is the problem, I'd suggest downloading the node (there's a link to download it in the Firebase console) and checking its size.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I responded to your questions as an update in the question above.

Comment: The only mention of a 1MB limit in that documentation link is about triggers for Cloud Functions. Since you're not using Cloud Functions yet, that limit can't be causing this problem.

Comment: 800KB is quite some JSON, but should be loadable on most modern devices. It depends a bit on the structure though, as it's not just kept as a single 800KB string in memory. It's more likely we can help if you show us the actual data, and show some debugging results, like how long it takes for each line of code to execute. That will also give us a chance to consider your second question, which will likely involve some sort of [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data) and [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I posted the JSON tree and also my debugging results.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Are you saying that the ` self.ref.child(MP.adminID).removeValue()` call is made, but it never completes? That'd be unexpected, as the remove call is fairly lightweight between client and server (although it could be a lot of work on the server, depending on your data structure). Can you update the code to show the logging you added for timing steps? This would then also show what step it reaches and where it stops working.

Comment: No, the `.removeValue()` call is made and completes. It's the next line that never completes. The writing the copied information to the new node. It just hangs. Oh, and the timing numbers correspond with the numbered parts of the code (in the comments). I'll update to make it more clear.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see what might be going wrong then. You don't actually have to delete the data in step 3, since you're overwriting it in step 4 anyway. But I don't think that is the cause of the problem. You might be down to your plan of moving the data in smaller chunks, which requires that you can either query a subset of the data, or know the child nodes. Given their names, you seem to know the child nodes, so you could move them over one at a time: `budgets`, `dailyHabits`, `dailyJobs`, etc.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that's exactly what I opted to do. I just opted to move the `snapshot.children` over one at at time. No problems. Seems to work just fine. Side note: I do have to delete the data in step 3. If I just overwrite, some users don't have all the data nodes, and so previous user data will still be there. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Final version that seems to work:

```
func copyToTestingNode() {
            
    // 1 . create copy of user and then modify the copy
    guard var copiedUser = user else { print("copied user error"); return }
    let adminRef = ref.child(MP.adminID)
    copiedUser.userID = MP.adminID
    copiedUser.householdInfo.subscriptionExpiryDate = 2500000000
    
    // 2. get a snapshot of the copied user's info
    ref.child(user.userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (userSnapshot) in
                    
        // 3. remove any existing data at admin node, and then...
        adminRef.removeValue { (error, dbRef) in
            
            if (error != nil) { print("Yikes!") }

            // 4. ...copy the new user info to the admin node one node at a time (if user has a lot of data)
            var totalNodesCopied = 0
            
            for item in userSnapshot.children {
                guard let snap = item as? DataSnapshot else { print("snap error"); return }
                
                self.ref.child(MP.adminID).child(snap.key).setValue(snap.value) { (error, adminRef) in
                    
                    totalNodesCopied += 1
                    
                    if totalNodesCopied == userSnapshot.childrenCount {
                        print("ALL DONE COPYING!!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```